# Should we say 10 rakat sunnat moqada prayer at the Friday prayers?

Tags: sunnah, hanafi, jumuah

In accordance with the Hanafi school I want to know about  the Friday prayer, that whether it's compulsory to say 10 Rakat Sunnat moqada in the Friday prayers?

Answer (score 1):

There are two types of sunnat:

1. Sunnat-e-Moqeda
2. Sunnat-e-GairMoqeda

*Sunnat-e-Moqeda* which Mohammed (Sallahu Alaihi wasallam) perform daily, and *Sunnat-e-GairMoqeda* which he didn't perform at times.

*Sunnat-e-Moqeda* is we should perform, it's compulsory, as we are followers of Mohammed (Sallahu Alaihi Wasallam).

So we need to perform 10 rakat of Sunnat-e-Moqeda after Namaz-e-Juma.

Answer (score 0):

I read in my Urdu-language guide to Salah that Friday Prayer is thus:

4 Sunnat Moakkadah
2 Faraz
4 Sunnat Moakkadah
2 Sunnat Ghair Moakkadah
2 Nafil

I then confirmed this with my maternal uncle, whose Islamic knowledge is of A-1 grade Insyallah.